# Bash alias is not executing as expected

Tags: bash, alias

Having read a little of alises, I wanted to try one but I couldn't get it to work.  Why does this alias not work?

```
$ printenv PWD
/home/vm
$ alias testpwd="$PWD"
$ testpwd
-bash: /home/vm: Is a directory
```

But if I do this with echo, it does work?

```
$ alias testpwd="echo $PWD"
$ testpwd
/home/vm
```

I don't understand why the first test didnt work?

Comment: `$PWD` contains the pathname to the current directory; what are you expecting would happen if you run it as a command?

Comment: An alias is (the start of) a *command.* A directory is not a command, so Bash says "/home/vm: Is a directory".

Comment: Ah I realise the problem after your comment ilkkachu.  Thanks

Comment: ... it should work in bash if you set the autocd shell option

Comment: It will work if you simply replace `$PWD` with `pwd` so that the shell doesn't interpret it as an attempt to run the current working directory as a command and instead, is actually an alias to the actual command: `alias testpwd="pwd"`

Answer (score 1):

Both examples work correctly in that they do what you have told them to do. The `alias` command defines a word that represents the remainder of the definition:

```
alias testpwd="echo $PWD"
```

When you use `testpwd` as the first word in a command you can consider that the word is replaced with `echo $PWD`. However, because you wrapped the command expansion in double quotes the value `$PWD` was evaluated when you executed the command *definition*. So in this case it was saved as `echo /home/vm`. Whenever you run `testpwd` you will get `/home/vm` output, regardless of your *current* value for `$PWD`. (As usual, use 'single' quotes instead of "doubles" to avoid immediate evaluation of variables by the shell.)

The first example works the same way; this defines `testpwd` to mean `"$PWD"`:

```
alias testpwd="$PWD"
```

Now when you run `testpwd` you can consider (as before) it is replaced by the current value of `"$PWD"` at the point the alias was defined, in other words `/home/vm`. This attempts to execute what was the current directory as a command, which will fail miserably:

```
-bash: /home/vm: Is a directory
```